# Compilation Error in Micronaut Data Repository with Kotlin Interfaces for Hibernate Reactive Entities

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm encountering a compilation error when defining Kotlin interfaces for my Hibernate Reactive entities and using Micronaut Data repositories. The error occurs specifically when implementing the `AddressRepository.findAllByCityStateId(Long id)` method.

Here are my entity classes in Java:

```java
@Serdeable
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE")
public class State {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_STATE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_STATE", sequenceName = "SQ_STATE", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // getter and setters
}

@Serdeable
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_CITY")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_CITY", sequenceName = "SQ_CITY", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", nullable = false)
    private State state;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // getter and setters
}


@Serdeable
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_ADDRESS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_ADDRESS", sequenceName = "SQ_ADDRESS", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID", nullable = false)
    private City city;

    @NotNull
    private String cep;

    // getter and setters
}
```

And here is the corresponding repository and controller:

```java
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends ReactorCrudRepository<Address, Long> {
    @Join(value = "city.state")
    Flux<Address> findAllByCityStateId(Long id);
}

@Controller("/addresses")
public class AddressController {
    protected final AddressRepository addressRepository;

    public AddressController(AddressRepository addressRepository) {
        this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    }

    @Get("/list")
    public Flux<Address> list(@NonNull Long id) {
        return addressRepository.findAllByCityStateId(id);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to create Kotlin interfaces for these entities, I face a compilation error:

```kotlin
interface State {
    var id: Long?
    var name: String
}

interface City {
    var id: Long?
    var name: String
    var state: State
}

interface Address {
    var id: Long?
    var city: City
    var cep: String
}
```

```java
@Serdeable
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE")
public class StateEntity implements State {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_STATE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_STATE", sequenceName = "SQ_STATE", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    // overriding getter and setters
}

@Serdeable
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITY")
public class CityEntity implements City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_CITY")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_CITY", sequenceName = "SQ_CITY", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", nullable = false)
    private StateEntity state;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    public StateEntity getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = (StateEntity) state;
    }
    
    // overriding other getters and setters
}

@Serdeable
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class AddressEntity implements Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_ADDRESS")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_ADDRESS", sequenceName = "SQ_ADDRESS", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID", nullable = false)
    private CityEntity city;

    @NotNull
    private String cep;

    public CityEntity getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = (CityEntity) city;
    }
    
    // overriding other getters and setters
}
```

The error message is:

```
Unable to implement Repository method: AddressRepository.findAllByCityStateId(Long id).
Cannot query entity [AddressEntity] on non-existent property: CityStateId
```

Is this behavior expected, or is it a bug? If it's expected, what is the recommended approach to defining Kotlin interfaces for such entity mappings in a Micronaut Data environment with Hibernate Reactive?